# Why is "They had started dating when they were at school" gramatical?

Tags: past-perfect

(1) They had started dating when they were at school.

(2) I had visited the museum twice when I lived in China.

(2') I visited the museum twice when I lived in China.

I thought past perfect can be used only when a time adjunct represents a point in time. therefore, (2) is not grammatical because its time adjunct 'when I lived in China' represents an interval in time instead of a point, while (2') is grammatical. If this is correct, (1) should be ungrammatical, because its time adjunct 'when they were at school' represents an interval in time. But, I recently learn that (1) is acceptable. I'd like to know why?

Comment: They're all grammatical. Past perfect is used to establish a time-period context.

Comment: @Robusto, all of (1),(2) and (2') ?

Comment: (1) _They had started dating when they were at secondary school_ defaults to their starting dating when at school. The _They had already started dating when they were at [/started]  secondary school_ sense would usually be rephrased.

Comment: The past perfect is commoner in written English where it almost invariably refers to an action in the past that has now finished - hence the use of the past perfect for providing context to the main theme, which is expressed in the simple past: "They had started dating when they were at school. They had married after university - a union that had produced two children. *They were now in the process of buying a second home.*" - Italics indicate the current theme.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I have two questions. 
Q1) What is the difference between (1) and (1'). (1')They started dating when they were at school.
Q2) Is (2) grammatical? I thought past perfect can be used only when a time adjunct gives a point in time,
which explains the ungrammaricallity of (2), where the time adjunct gives an interval in time instead of a point.

Comment: The main reason to use past perfect is to contrast the action to something later, but also in the past. How would you know which happened first? Add the word 'had'. *They had started dating when X* sets up the next sentence to say that Y happened later. Later, they saw each other less often precisely because of shool work.